# Open all Grid Engine .e, .o, .pe and .po files in Sublime by default?

Tags: sublimetext3, sungridengine

Windows user. I want Sublime to open files as described in title. The problem is, each job creates it's own extension.

e.g. submit job number 1111111 and get files job.e1111111, job.o1111111, etc.

Within Windows these are unrecognised file types. One can assign Sublime to open them but obviously the next job will have a different job number and a different extension.

Thanks

Comment: The job of association between file extensions and what should open them falls to Windows and not Sublime; so unless Windows has the ability to apply a range of file extensions to an association, I don't think this is possible.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if Windows offers a way to do this. There are probably some workarounds. You should probably ask for those on https://superuser.com/

However, I think the correct solution would be to assign output filenames to your jobs.
If you wish to include the job IDs also with your custom filenames, you can easily do this via the `$JOB_ID` pseudo environment variable.

Simply use the `-o` and `-e` arguments with your `qsub` command. You can define a pattern to have your outputs named `job1111111-stdout.txt` and `job1111111-stderr.txt`.

Source and more information: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/820-0699/i999036/index.html